# Data in a union being overwritten

Tags: c, pointers, struct, unions

I am struggling with this problem at the moment. I have a union, which has a member struct + variables, the member struct also contains a member struct + variables, this member struct contains variables.

I have found that when trying to assign values to specific variables I end up overwriting some of the previously assigned data. I have a good feeling this is due to a pointer not being incremented. Some example code below:

```
struct Scale
{
    char Scale_Name[5];
    char notes[10];
};

struct Instrument
{
    char Inst_Name[5];
    struct Scale scales[5];
};

union Whole_Inst
{
    char InstrumentCount;
    struct Instrument Instruments[2]; 
};

union Whole_Inst Instrument1;

int main(void)
{
    char i, j, k;
    char TempArr[5] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05};
    char NUMBER_OF_INST = 1;

    Instrument1.InstrumentCount = TempArr[0];

    printf("InstCount   = 0x%x\n", Instrument1.InstrumentCount);   

    for(j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_INST; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Instrument1.Instruments[0].Inst_Name[i] = TempArr[i+1];
            printf("\nInstName[%d] = 0x%x", i,  
            Instrument1.Instruments[0].Inst_Name[i]);   
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nInstCount   = 0x%x\n", i,  Instrument1.InstrumentCount);   

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
InstCount   = 0x1

InstName[0] = 0x2
InstName[1] = 0x3
InstName[2] = 0x4
InstName[3] = 0x5

InstCount   = 0x4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Kind Regards
David

Comment: Why are you using a union? Shouldn't it be a struct?

Comment: When you set `Instrument1.InstrumentCount`, you're actually overwriting the instrument data - union members map to the same memory space, so changing one member changes all union members. It doesn't make sense that you use a union for that.

Comment: Do you know what `union` is for? This is exactly what it is doing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because C book needed urgently. It is a shame to ask this kind of question, It is enough to open the wikipedia to see: In `C and C++, untagged unions are expressed nearly exactly like structures (structs), except that **each data member begins at the same location in memory.**`

Answer (score 4):

Your `union` allows you to store **either** a count or an array of `Inustrument`s, but not both. The two pieces of data share the same memory. If you change one, you write over the memory used by the other.

If you want to store both a count and an array, you need to use a `struct` instead of a `union`.